# Alternate visas to the Australia e601 visa

Tags: visas, australia

I was banned to enter Australia for 3 years for overstaying. I was told that the ban only applies to the particular visa I applied for (e601 - ETA). Does that mean the ban doesn't apply to the e600 visa? Or are both e600 and e601 considered the same type of visa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [re-entry ban fact sheet](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa/visa-about-to-expire-or-expired/status-resolution-service/re-entry-bans-fact-sheet) states that there are two exceptions to a re-entry ban.

1. Apply for a permanent visa. However,

> Re-entry bans are mostly imposed on applications for temporary visas.
>   The ban does not prevent you from seeking a permanent visa, though the
>   Department may consider your immigration history when making future
>   immigration decisions.

2. Request that the ban be set aside for a single visa application. If granted, after the trip, the ban is still in force.

> Requests will only be considered if you can prove there are
>   compassionate or compelling circumstances that affect the interests of
>   an Australian citizen or permanent resident or an eligible New Zealand
>   citizen.